# Spring Boot: How to prevent URL override when using a BaseController for CRUD operations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, request-mapping

I have a Spring Boot application and I have implemented a base controller that handles CRUD operations for all my entities. I have also created a BrandController that extends the base controller and a BrandRepository that implements CrudRepository. The problem is that when I try to access the endpoints for the BrandController such as /api/brands, I get a 404 error, but I can access them on /brands How can I fix this so that the endpoints are accessible with /api/entitys?

Here is the code for the BrandController:

```java
package parc.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import parc.model.concrete.Brand;
import parc.repository.BrandRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/brands")
public class BrandController extends BaseController<Brand, BrandRepository> {

    private final BrandRepository repository;

    public BrandController(BrandRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the BaseController:

```java
package parc.controller;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

public class BaseController<T, R extends CrudRepository<T, Long>> {

    private R repository;

    public BaseController(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return (List<T>) repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public T create(@RequestBody T entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public T getById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public T update(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody T entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

And finally the code for the BrandRepository:

```java
package parc.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import parc.model.concrete.Brand;

public interface BrandRepository extends CrudRepository<Brand, Long> {

}
```

I'm not a pro in Spring Boot so I'll appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: why do you use inheritance for your controllers?

Comment: I have so many entities, so I want to implement 1 base controller that will have the basic crud and then make my other controllers implement it to be using it by default and then I can add my own endpoints to the EntityControllers, that's the first thing that came to my mind to do so. 
Is there a better way ?

Comment: You can just have a basePath variable in the BaseController that is injected from the child classes.

Comment: You could also have only one `CrudController` for all your entities that uses a `@PathVariable` to identify which class to handle and only `JsonObject` as datatypes - but I think this could get a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @bw0248 how can I do so in my case? I'm still not very familiar with spring.

Comment: @cyberbrain I think that would work maybe, but as you said is not practical. It would be perfect if there were a Path extender annotation or something like so.

Comment: didn't try it, but [`@RequestMapping` JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path()) say it supports relative paths, so try to use them in the BaseController method annotations.

Comment: @cyberbrain I already tried it that way but it was overriden. I put @RequestMapping("/api") on the BaseController and the @RequestMapping("/brands") on the BrandController.
I still can't access /api/brands and access /brands instead.

Comment: The code you have shared has no mapping to `/brands`, so you must have something else going on. Try setting the log level of `org.springframework.web` to `TRACE` and check the startup output for mappings.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I suggested that you keep the class annotations as they are, but use relative paths (=> they do *not* start with a `/`) on the methods annotations.

Comment: Controller extends Repository?.. This is bad idea right from the start. Those are different layers. You're overcomplicating stuff. Just make separate controllers for your entities - or better say for your business operations.

Comment: @cyberbrain I didn't understand at first, so based on what you said, I tried instead of @RequestMapping("/api/brands") using @RequestMapping("api/brands") on top of the BrandController, and now the BaseController has no request mapping, but still the mapping goes by default to the naming /brands.

Comment: @Oliver I understand tho, I too don't understand the problem with the mapping nor I understand how Spring does it.
Can you suggest me a way to debug the path trace ?

Comment: @ILyaCyclone I'm not familiar with spring but I'm just templating the repository not really extending it to the controller. and that so that I can use the base controller elements as long as leaving the possibility to add custom mappings on the concrete Controller classes.
I Have well over 15 models in the project, making the same rest controllers again and again will be very painful especially if I wanted to extend to more models later. and now it works fine, but I asked the question to know how the paths are getting overridden (the issue is just about the paths ).

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in application.yml?
maybe setting the following code will work:

in application.yml:

```yaml
server:
    contextPath: /api
```

and the BrandController:

```java
package parc.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import parc.model.concrete.Brand;
import parc.repository.BrandRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/brands")
public class BrandController extends BaseController<Brand, BrandRepository> {

    private final BrandRepository repository;

    public BrandController(BrandRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

}
```

Comment: Setting servlet context path doesn't make any sense for this question.

Comment: I tried to add the server param, here is my application.yml now:
```
rsa:
  private-key: classpath:certs/private.pem
  public-key: classpath:certs/public.pem

server:
  contextPath: /api
```
But it still didn't change the path tho.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your problem now. Have you tried to change the class BaseController into abstract?